# Comparing two metaclasses (AnyClass)

Tags: swift, comparison, metaclass

Is there any way to implement these custom comparison functions in the current state of Swift?

```
/// Tests if `lhs` is the same class as (or a subclass of) `rhs`.
public func == (lhs: AnyClass, rhs: AnyClass) -> Bool {
  fatalError("unimplemented")
}

/// Tests if `lhs` is the same class as `rhs`.
public func === (lhs: AnyClass, rhs: AnyClass) -> Bool {
  fatalError("unimplemented")
}
```

I would use them like so:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

A.self == A.self // true
B.self == A.self // true
A.self == B.self // false

A.self === A.self // true
B.self === A.self // false
A.self === B.self // false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider the `===` tests already work since they test the memory address of the class objects.

Comment: also looking for the same thing for my sqlite orm lib